# Most recent date for each group

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a query that extracts only the observations on the last date for a given ID. I am using the following:

```
select to_char(a.from_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') as fromdate, a.portfolio,a.var1,a.var2, 
from table1 a, table2 b
where 1=1
and  a.portfolio_ref=b.por_ref 
and a.from_date in ( SELECT MAX(a.from_date) from table1 group by portfolio);
```

However, I still obtain multiple different dates per portfolio.
What I obtain:

```
| Date        | Portfolio | Var1 | Var2 |
|-------------|-----------|------|------|
| 05-07-2021  | AA        | 1    | 15   |
| 05-07-2021  | AA        | 2    | 16   |
| 05-07-2021  | AA        | 3    | 17   |
| 06-03-2020  | AA        | 4    | 18   |
| 06-03-2020  | AA        | 5    | 19   |
| 08-03-2020  | AA        | 6    | 20   |
| 22-02-2019  | AA        | 7    | 21   |
| 01-01-2019  | BB        | 8    | 22   |
| 01-01-2019  | BB        | 9    | 23   |
| 02-05-2020  | BB        | 10   | 24   |
| 02-05-2020  | BB        | 11   | 25   |
|             | …         | ..   | ..   |
| 07-09-2020  | KK        | 12   | 26   |
| 05-08-2019  | KK        | 13   | 27   |
| 05-08-2019  | KK        | 14   | 28   |
```

The solution I would like to obtain:

```
| Date        | Portfolio | Var1 | Var2 |
| 05-07-2021  | AA        | 1    | 15   |
| 05-07-2021  | AA        | 2    | 16   |
| 05-07-2021  | AA        | 3    | 17   |
| 02-05-2020  | BB        | 10   | 24   |
| 02-05-2020  | BB        | 11   | 25   |
|       ...   | …         | ..   | ..   |
| 07-09-2020  | KK        | 12   | 26   |
```

Why I presumably is having troubles using similar codes suggested here in Stack Owerflow

1. The date appear to be incorrectly specified in SQL, which is why I convert the date variable, from_date, using: `to_char(a.from_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') as fromdate`. To clarify:

`````
    | Wrong date | Date (to_char) |
    |------------|----------------|
    | 21-07-06   | 06-07-2021     |
    | 21-07-06   | 06-07-2021     |
    | 20-03-06   | 06-03-2020     |
    
    | 19-02-22   | 22-02-2019     |
    | 19-01-01   | 01-01-2019     |
    | 19-01-01   | 01-01-2019     |
    | 20-05-02   | 02-05-2020     | ````

2. I have multiple observations of a given ID on its maximum date.
`````

Comment: *"I convert the date variable, from_date"* - Just to clarify terminology, it's a value, not a variable. Tables aren't full of variables. And, a date is its own datatype in SQL, just like numbers where `1234` can be represented as `1,234`, `1.234`, `1.2e3` etc, so how it's displayed and its internal value are two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your point `1.` is **not correct**, the point `2.` is *right*.

Your *actuall* problem is in the wrong subquery filter

```
a.from_date in ( SELECT MAX(a.from_date) from table1 group by portfolio)
```

That is doing a *different* thing as you think. (Basically you allow all maximal `from_date`s - independent of a portfolio).

Let's illustrate it on a simplified example - leaving out all unnecessary stuff.

```
create table tab as
select date'2021-01-01' from_date, 'AA' portfolio from dual union all
select date'2021-01-01' from_date, 'AA' portfolio from dual union all
select date'2020-01-01' from_date, 'AA' portfolio from dual union all
select date'2020-01-01' from_date, 'BB' portfolio from dual;


select from_date, portfolio
from tab
where from_date in (select max(from_date) from tab group by portfolio);
```

The query returns

```
FROM_DATE           PO
------------------- --
01.01.2021 00:00:00 AA
01.01.2021 00:00:00 AA
01.01.2020 00:00:00 AA
01.01.2020 00:00:00 BB
```

The line three is *what you do not want*. You get it because the `from_date`ist the MAX date of the *portfolio BB*.

You can get rid of it by adding the `portfolio` to the subquery

```
select from_date, portfolio
from tab
where (portfolio,from_date) in (select portfolio, max(from_date) from tab group by portfolio);

FROM_DATE           PO
------------------- --
01.01.2021 00:00:00 AA
01.01.2021 00:00:00 AA
01.01.2020 00:00:00 BB
```

So, now remains the first problem of duplicated resuls due to ties on MAX date.

The best way is to use *analytic function* ROW_NUMBER with

`partition by` your columns that you call `ID` - here `portfolio`.

`order by` the columns defining the *order* with `DESC` - to get `1` for the row you need. You may want to add other columns to the `order by` to get a *deterministic* result. (Actually the columns from `partition by` and `order by` *should build a unique key in the table*).

```
select 
 from_date, portfolio,
 row_number() over (partition by portfolio order by from_date desc) as rn
from tab

FROM_DATE           PO         RN
------------------- -- ----------
01.01.2021 00:00:00 AA          1
01.01.2021 00:00:00 AA          2
01.01.2020 00:00:00 AA          3
01.01.2020 00:00:00 BB          1
```

Full query

```
with port as (
select 
 from_date, portfolio,
 row_number() over (partition by portfolio order by from_date desc) as rn
from tab)
select 
 from_date, portfolio
from port
where rn = 1;

FROM_DATE           PO
------------------- --
01.01.2021 00:00:00 AA
01.01.2020 00:00:00 BB
```

Comment: Thank you, Marmite. I really appreciate your answer. This is my second time using SQL, so please bear with me. Concerning my point ````1.```` it is necessary for me to do some sort of conversion, since the dates are loaded incorrectly (I have updated my question)

Comment: Hi again. However, I may not have made it entirely clear in my question, but I am not interested in removing row 2 (RN=2), since it contains different values of var1 and var2 as shown in my example. I am sorry. I tried to replace my code with your suggestion
````where (portfolio,from_date) in (select portfolio, max(from_date) from tab group by portfolio);````
However, it did not help - I still obtain row 3 (RN=3), which I do not want (I only want observations on 01.01.2021 for AA)

Comment: @CecilieS.K please EDIT you question, add *sample data* and expected result. Add clear formulations, such as: *for each combination of `portfolio`, `var1` and `var2` I expect only one row with the highest `from_date`.

Comment: I cannot include _sample data_ since it is confidential. I tried my best to include the expected results using a table for illustrative purposes. The terminology is new to me, which is why I asked people to bear with me in the question. Thank you for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the RANK() window function. You then would have to use a subquery to fetch all the rows whose rank equals 1.

```
SELECT
 tbl.*
FROM
(SELECT 
 a.from_date fromdate, 
 a.portfolio,
 a.var1,
 a.var2,
 RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.portfolio ORDER BY a.from_date DESC) AS rank 
FROM 
 table1 a, 
INNER JOIN
 table2 b
ON
 a.portfolio_ref=b.por_ref
) tbl
WHERE
 tbl.rank = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, the ````from_date```` in itself yields incorrect dates; it confuses the day of the month with the year, which is why I think I need to include: ````to_char(a.from_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy')````

Comment: Yes, or you can use the TO_DATE() function if you believe the dates are stored as string